# Reallocating 1D array of integers, keeping original values, zeroing out rest

Tags: c, memcpy, realloc, calloc, memset

I would like to resize a one-dimensional array of integers, keep the values from the original array and initialise the new values with zeroes. So far, I have come up with two alternatives (a) using `calloc` and `memcpy`:

```
// Resizes composition
int compo_resize(int len, int *a) {

    // initialise new composition
    int *c = calloc(2*len, sizeof a[0]);

    if (c == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "calloc() failed");
        return LieanderErrorOutOfMemory;
    }

    // copy numbers from old to new composition
    memcpy(c, a, sizeof a[0] * len);

    // modify composition in-place
    *a = *c;

    // release memory
    free(c);

    return LieanderSuccess;
}
```

and (b) using `realloc` and `memset`:

```
// Resizes composition
int compo_resize(int len, int *a) {

    printf("Note: resizing composition...\n");

    // reallocate memory
    void *c = realloc(a, 2*len);

    if (c == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "realloc() failed");
        return LieanderErrorOutOfMemory;
    }
    else {
        // reassign pointer
        a = c;

        // zero out new elements
        memset(&a[len], 0, len * sizeof a[len]);
    }

    return LieanderSuccess;
}
```

I would say the second approach is more elegant and faster. However, when integrated into a larger program the code starts to return unexpected, incorrect values. Am I doing something wrong in the approach (b)? Am I missing something obvious?

The call to `combo_resize()` is `int retval = compo_resize(f->len, f->a)`, where `f` is a custom structure called a `pair`:

```
typedef struct {
    int  fac;  // multiplication factor
    int  idx;  // index of Lieander
    int  len;  // length of compositions
    int  kth;  // no. of elements in compositions
    int *a;    // composition 1
    int *b;    // composition 2
    int  num;  // natural no.
} pair;
```

Comment: Can you define "unexpected, incorrect values" more specifically? It's also odd that you're using `void*` to represent a temporary `int*` in that function. Just use the right type to avoid ambiguity. It sounds like you have a lot of undefined behaviour in here caused by using pointers after a `free` and so on.

Comment: In the second, `realloc(a, 2*len);` is wrong. It should be `realloc(a, 2 * len * sizeof *a);` You remembered the `sizeof` multiplier in your `memset`; any particular reason you left it out in your allocation ? Unrelated, the `memset` can simply use `a+len` for the target. And I hope the *caller* somehow knows what the new capacity is somehow, because there is no communication back to them of said same from that function.

Comment: You are freeing your newly created array right away. And the intention of `*a = *c;` is not clear at all.

Comment: `*a = *c` is equivalent to `a[0]=c[0]` which copies only one value. It does not copy the whole array.

Comment: @EugeneSh. My intention is to copy the values from the original array `a` to the new array `c`. Reassign the pointer `*a` to `*c` for the function to return a new array under `*a` and free the temporary memory `c`.

Comment: `*a = *c;` looks fishy to me, please show how you call `compo_resize`

Comment: @mabalenk please [edit]  your question and put clarification _there_. Also tell us what `f->a` is exactly. But probably you should use one of the upvoted answers below and call the function like that: `compo_resize(f->len, &f->a)`

Comment: mabalenk, Why `2*` in `realloc(a, 2*len)`?  I'd expect a signature like `compo_resize(int *a, int oldsize, int newsize)`.

Comment: @chux, `f->len` is the current length of the array `a`. I would like to double the size of the original array. That's why I use `2*len`.

Comment: mabalenk, Calling a function `compo_resize(int len, int *a)` then mis-leads as the parameter `len` is not the resize length.  Calling the function something like `compo_double_the_size(int len, int *a)` would be more consistent with your coding goal.  "Reallocating 1D array of integers" gives no hint that size is doubling but implies a potential increase or decrease in size.

Comment: Pedantic note: `if (c == NULL) {` is not certainly an out-of-memory indication when `len == 0`.  Code could use `if (c == NULL && len == 0) {` instead.

Answer (score 2):

First, You need to pass the address of the pointer you want to update, otherwise the pointer wont be modified outside the function. Because realloc might change the location of your data if it cannot find a long enough continuous region.

Second, make sure you are strict on the size of your array versus the size in bytes.

```
// Resizes composition
int compo_resize(int len, int **a) {

    printf("Note: resizing composition...\n");

    // reallocate memory
    void *c = realloc(*a, sizeof(int) * 2 * len);

    if (c == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "realloc() failed");
        return LieanderErrorOutOfMemory;
    }
    else {
        // reassign pointer
        *a = c;

        // zero out new elements
        memset(&c[len], 0, sizeof(int) * len);
    }

    return LieanderSuccess;
}
```

Comment: Note that `2 * len * sizeof(int)` can overflow cases when `sizeof(int) * 2 * len` does not: (`len > INT_MAX/2`). Recommend the 2nd.

Answer (score 2):

The `int *a` parameter needs to be replaced with `int **a` because you want to change the pointer on behalf of the caller.

```
// Resizes composition
int compo_resize(int len, int **a) {

    printf("Note: resizing composition...\n");

    // reallocate memory
    int *c = realloc(*a, sizeof(c[0])*2*len);

    if (c == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "realloc() failed");
        return LieanderErrorOutOfMemory;
    }
    else {
        // reassign pointer
        *a = c;

        // zero out new elements
        memset(&c[len], 0, len * sizeof c[len]);
    }

    return LieanderSuccess;
}
```

Comment: Note that `2*len*sizeof(c[0])` can overflow cases when `sizeof(c[0]) * 2 * len` does not: (`len > INT_MAX/2`). Recommend the 2nd.

Comment: @chux Good point. I've rearranged the expression as per your suggestion. It would be even better to use `size_t len` instead of `int len`, but I want to keep it as close to OP's original as possible.

Comment: @IanAbbott, I have changed the code according to your suggestion. It compiles, but I obtain unexpected, incorrect values at the end of program execution. The array `a` contains integers which are reduced and cancelled out until a certain combination is reached. There are many `pairs` of combinations that are summed up in the end. Now, this sum differs from time to time. Which is wrong and unexpected.

Comment: @mabalenk The problem is in your unposted code.  Post a [mcve].

Comment: @mabalenk I hope you realize that you now need to call the function like `retval = compo_resize(f->len, &f->a);` (note the `&` added to the second argument).

Answer (score 0):

1- Do not free allcoated memmory as you will used it after the function return.

2- Consider free old *a after copying it to *c.

3- Change function declaration from:

```
int compo_resize(int len, int *a);
```

to

```
int compo_resize(int len, int **a);
```

because you want to update the value of the pointer itself to point to a newly created array.

Comment: As mentioned in man(3) realloc: `if the area pointed to was moved, a free(ptr) is done. `

Comment: @Tezrig, I cannot get your point, the user who asked the question did not mention any realloc in the first method. You just assumed I am addressing his second trial!